# Nodejs mssql filestream data type returning buffer?

Tags: node.js, sql-server, node-sqlserver

I am storing large files as a filestream in SQL Server. When I query SQL Server, the table shows a long string of data like this for each file/row:

```
 0x504B03041400060008000000210032916F5766010000A5050000130008025B436F6E74656E74...........
```

When I query the same table using node-mssql:

```
mainFile = await rows.query(`Select mainFile from RoeseJobsFile where ID = ${mainID}`)
```

I get something like this:

[image]

I am guessing the first one is hexadecimal representation of the file. Why is the node query different. My end goal is to send the file to the front end to be viewed. How do I send a file like this?